# fopen() is not returning a resource

Tags: php

So I have this bit of code below to determine if the $this->stream is a resource. If it is not a resource then it should use fopen to create a resource, but it doesn't seem to work.

How do I make $this->stream a resource I thought fopen() was designed to open or create a file if it doesn't exist. Anything opened or created should be a resource correct? Why would I hit the code to throw an exception?

```
if (!is_resource($this->stream)) {

    $this->errorMessage = null;
    set_error_handler(array($this, 'customErrorHandler'));
    $this->stream = fopen($this->url, 'a');

    restore_error_handler();

    if (!is_resource($this->stream)) {
        $this->stream = null;
        throw new \UnexpectedValueException(sprintf('The stream or file "%s" could not be opened: '.$this->errorMessage, $this->url));
    }
}
```

Comment: And you get no error message? Are you sure your error handler is catching any possible errors? What is `$this->url`?

Comment: $this->url points to a log file kinda like '/var/www/site/file.log'...the error I am purposefully throwing with 'throw new' is the problematic file. I am not sure why fopen isn't creating the file though as a resource. Any suggestions?

Comment: And `$this->errorMessage` says what? I'd assume you're catching any errors produced by `fopen` there...?!

Comment: Failed to open stream No such file or Directory. Which the file doesn't exist so fopen should create it correct?

Comment: Does the *directory* exist? Because it won't create the directory structure AFAIK.

Comment: I assume the code you posted is still in development. How are your current php.ini log settings? Do you get any  messages when running your code in case you set `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);`?